# A non-blocking server with java.io

Tags: java, sockets, io

Everybody knows that java IO is *blocking*, and java NIO is *non-blocking*. In IO you will have to use the thread per client pattern, in NIO you can use one thread for all clients.

Now my question follows: is it possible to make a *non-blocking* design using **only** the Java IO api. (not NIO)

I was thinking about a pattern like this (obviously very simplified);

```
        List<Socket> li;
        for (Socket s : li) {
            InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
            byte[] data = in.available();
            in.read(data);
            // processData(data); (decoding packets, encoding outgoing packets
        }
```

**Also note that the client will always be ready for reading data.**

What are your opinions on this? Will this be suitable for a server that should at least hold a few hundred of clients without major performance issues?

Comment: In what way do you think this will be nonblocking?

Comment: You seem to have the right idea, i.e. you simulate non-blocking I/O using `available` method and polling for clients. But EJP answer is correct

Comment: @JordanKaye I assume this is nonblocking because I only read the amount of bytes that are ready

Answer (score 4):

It is possible but pointless. There is no select() in java.net, so you are reduced to polling the sockets, which implies sleeping between polls, and you can't tell how long to sleep for, so you will sleep for longer than necessary, so you will waste time, add latency, etc; or else you must sleep for stupidly short intervals and so consume pointless CPU.

For a mere few hundred clients there is no possible objection to the conventional use of a thread per connection.

I don't know what 'the client will always be ready for reading data' means. You can't tell that from the server, and if it isn't ready, writes to it can block, which will upset your applecard completely.

Comment: +1 and `available()` seems quirky at best across platforms. The best way to attempt this IMHO would be polling each socket with a timeout (SO_TIMEOUT socket opt) which again ... is simply not going to be better than a single connection per thread solution.

Comment: 'the client will always be ready for reading data': meaning that there's an infinite loop that looks for available data, and processes it using worker threads (Maybe not very relevant, just a note so you know that the server won't block on writing). Thanks for your input, very helpful :).

Comment: @Jon 'Ready for reading' and 'block on writing' are completely unrelated. Your statement doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Jon ... and the server will indeed block on writing if there is no space in the socket send buffer, which is caused by the peer reading slower than the local host is sending.