# How does Java NIO's selector check for available events under the hood?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, nio

A similar question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712847/a-non-blocking-server-with-java-io), but I would like to place it again, hoping that someone would help clear out a couple of things. As an experiment, I tried writing a naive "non-blocking" server in Java without using NIO, where essentially three threads are needed:

1. Main server thread - `accept()`s new socket connections, and puts each new socket in a queue
2. Reading worker thread - goes through each socket in the queue, and reads a little bit out of each socket's input stream, and stores it in an `InputQueue`
3. Writing worker thread - depending on when the incoming request gets read out of each socket, this worker would loop over all sockets where a response is needed, and once again, write a few bytes of response on every take.

In the previous question, it was pointed out that Java NIO's `select()` mechanism is far better than polling on each socket, and sleeping a little after every take through the queue. I know how select works in theory, but the main thing that I struggle to understand is the following: if polling is bad and inefficient, how does `select()` do it under the hood?

**UPDATE:** I found [this page](http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/poll-vs-select.html) which gives a bit more light on how the native `select()` works under the hood. What is interesting is that indeed, my initial speculations seem to be right: `select()` works in a linear fashion, probing each of the requested file descriptors, similar to what a polling mechanism would do:

> They both [`select()` and `poll()`] handle file descriptors in a
>   linear way. The more descriptors you ask them to check, the slower
>   they get. As soon as you go beyond perhaps a hundred file descriptors
>   or so - of course depending on your CPU and hardware - you will start
>   noticing that the mere waiting for file descriptor activity and the
>   following checking which file descriptor that it was, takes a
>   significant time and becomes a bottle neck.

Comment: First ask yourself the question: is it worth the trouble going non blocking? In the very vast majority of scenarios, this isn't...

Comment: I know, my example is entirely for learning and illustrative purposes at this point in time.

Comment: Poor quality link. Unsubstantiated guesswork. Don't believe everything you read on the a Internet.

Answer (score 2):

It calls the `select()` method in the operating system, which:

- deems a socket to be readable if there is data or a FIN in the socket receive buffer
- deems a socket to be writable is there is space in the socket send buffer (i.e. most of the time).

Comment: Those I understand, but my question is, even on the OS level, it must be doing some sort of timesharing and polling, right? Imagine if there are 10 open sockets. What I imagine select would do is almost the same as my code in the naive nonblocking server would do, but on a much lower level. Am I correct?

Comment: No, it blocks internally until one of those conditions becomes true or the timeout expires. The only linear behaviour arises when you traverse the FD_SET in your application code. It's not how it works internally, whatever your link may claim.

Comment: Do you have a better resource? I am really, really interested to learn how this works. Maybe, I will go grab this book: http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/013490012X/

Comment: W.R. Stevens, *TCP/IP Illustrated,* volume II.